# Why are links not working when I have a decent reputation?

Tags: support, markdown

I have posted a second answer to [Where can I find a working example of how to remotely invoke an OSGi service contained within Eclipse Virgo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774164/where-can-i-find-a-working-example-of-how-to-remotely-invoke-an-osgi-service-con), but the links are not formatting properly. I have a reputation of 589, so why is this? The links are necessary background to my answer.

Comment: I would guess it's the HTML. Stack Overflow uses Markdown.

Comment: I guess HTML and Markdown don't mix that well. Try using HTML `<a>` links as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you forget about the `<ol>` and `<li>`, and other such unnecessary elements and use the Markdown then it displays fine, such as:

```
- Download CXF single bundle distribution from [here][1] - I used 1.3.0.
```

I didn't need to dissect your post to discover this, just removed the first couple of those tags (and their corresponding end tags.)

*Update: I've taken the liberty of editing your post accordingly, formatting is still not perfect (in my opinion - I dropped the ordering, for one) but your links are at least showing.*

Comment: I can understand the use of HTML, though. Getting numbered lists right with Markdown, especially if you're going to use block elements in the list elements, is pretty annoying.

Comment: @lunboks Evidently just as awkward trying to hack around that, too.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Thanks for taking the liberty. I'll take a look and see if the post needs further tidy up. Seems like there should be some editing help around the issue of mixing html and markdown?

Comment: @GlynNormington If you click the help `[?]` in the top right of the editor, there's a note about it on the HTML tab, under the restriction for block-level elements.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown is [intentionally not parsed](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) inside of block-level HTML tags, as the comments suggest.

[Mr. Disappointment's recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128839/150235) for using Markdown for your entire post is the most straightforward solution to this problem, though you can also specify the link HTML manually so long as the opening tag has the exact form `<a href="" title="">`, where the title attribute is optional.